# Pandas dataframe can be accessed beyond its length

Tags: python, pandas

I have two time-series datasets, `stock1_data` and `stock2_data`. Stock 1's data starts earlier in time than stock 2's, but stock 2's ends later in time. I would like to shorten both datasets to their time intersection. Both datasets are ordered in increasing time.

I have tried doing this: 
`stock1_data = stock1_data.loc[(stock1_data['date'] >= stock2_data['date'][0])]`

and this:
`stock2_data = stock2_data.loc[(stock2_data['date'] <= stock1_data['date'][len(stock1_data.date) - 1])]`

The first line above works as intended, however the second line cuts off stock 2's data way too early. I looked at the length of stock 1, and it appears as though it can be accessed past its last index, given by len(stock1_data). It turns out it can be accessed by its original, unshortened length. Why is that?

Comment: Are the DataFrames ordered? Maybe you want `min(stock2_data['date'])` instead of `stock2_data['date'][0]` and `max(stock1_data['date'])` instead of `stock1_data['date'][len(stock1_data.date) - 1])]`?

Comment: The DataFrames are ordered. And yes your suggestion works! Any clue as to why my initial solution didn't work though?

Comment: You might find some context here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613753/why-does-python-allow-out-of-range-slice-indexes-for-sequences